# Which resources can help me learn how to use metasploit?

Tags: tools, penetration-test, vulnerability-scanners

I tried google search but I can't find good resources to learn how to use the metasploit framework.

Where would you suggest a beginner go to learn about using metasploit?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is, it's called [metasploit unleashed](http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Metasploit_Unleashed_Information_Security_Training).

It is an official metasploit wiki with lots of information. It is structured kind of as a tutorial/course, and it gets upgraded and updated regularly. It is probably the best place to start.

Answer (score 5):

[Security tube - Metasploit Megaprimer](http://www.securitytube.net/groups?operation=view&groupId=8)

More or less, everything I need I learnt from this one (however, for my needs Metasploit is more like additional tool then primary one).

Comment: then what is your primary tools?

Comment: @wizztjh - depends on what you need.. just looking for vulnerabilities, exploitation, security audits?

Comment: @wizztjh: like pootzko said, it depends on what you need for your task. Usually, my weapon of choice is - SET. However, I'm also using tools like Wireshark, NMAP, Jack the Reaper, Pyrit, Dradis, CCUP, and so on. For something you will use spoon and for something you'll use bulldozer :)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the ones already mentioned, there's a fairly new book been released about metasploit by No Starch press ([here](http://nostarch.com/metasploit.htm)).  I've not got too far into it yet but it looks pretty good so far.